# Runtime error in simple code of binary to decimal conversion

Tags: java, algorithm, binary, decimal

On Geeks for Geeks, I tried to solve a basic problem of binary-to-decimal conversion, but I get a runtime error and I don't know why.

```java
class Solution {
    public static int binarytodecimal(String str) {         
        int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
        int res = 0;
        int a = 1;
        while (n > 0) {
            int k = n % 10;
            res += k * a;
            a *= 2;
            n /= 10;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

This code normally works but why is it not passing all the test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to store the binary value in an int as most binary values would be too large for this.  Also, consider the value "100110110101".  When you convert to an it, the method presumes it is a **decimal** value.  So it is really 100,110,110,101 in `base 10` which far exceeds the value that an `int` can store.  So you will get a `NumberFormatException` from `Integer.parseInt()` since it is not a valid `int` (it's too large).  If the length is exactly `32` and the high order is set, result will be negative in keeping with two's complement representation.

So just use the String as passed to the method.

```
System.out.println(binaryToDecimal("110101100110110101"));
```

prints

```
219573
```

- iterate over the string and get the binary digit as an int (this uses codePoints to catch various character encodings).
- multiplying by 2 makes "space" to "append" the next digit using addition.
- then return the result.

```
public static int binaryToDecimal(String str) {
    int len = str.length();     
    if (len > 32) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "\nBinary string exceeds allowable width (%d)"
                        .formatted(len));
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int bit = Character.digit(str.codePointAt(i),2);
        if (bit != -1) {
            result = result * 2 + bit;
        } else {
            throw new NumberFormatException(
                    "Non-binary character '%c' found in %s.".formatted(str.charAt(i), str));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

An exception will be thrown if a non-binary digit is encountered.

Comment: thankyou, now I understood what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

An int is a 32 bit signed number, which means it can store only 10 decimal digits accurately (if they are 0's and 1's). That means `Integer.parseInt` will fail if given a binary number representing 2048 or more (ie with 11 or more digits).

Answer (score 0):

> #can you show what error you are facing

> #this is what i can just suggest

```
class Solution {
    public static int binarytodecimal(String str) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(str);
        int res = 0;
        int a = 1;
        while (n > 0) {
            int k = n % 10;
            res += k * a;
            a *= 2;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isBinary(String str) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (!(str.charAt(i) == '0' || str.charAt(i) == '1')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(System.in);
        int convertedValue;
        while (true) {
            String line = scanLine.nextLine();
            // check before conversion if the value is not string and is not binary
            if (isNumeric(line) && isBinary(line)) {
                convertedValue = binarytodecimal(line);
                System.out.println(convertedValue);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid attempt");
            }

        }

    }
```

}